# Difficulty adjusting spacing between articles using gap in CSS

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

I'm having a problem with the spacing between my articles in a specific section of my website. I have six articles in one section and I'm trying to use the CSS gap property to adjust the spacing between them. However, when I try to increase the gap value from 5px to 10px, it doesn't render as I expect.

- Here is my HTML code for the section :

```
    <section>
      <article></article>
      <article></article>
      <article></article>
      <article></article>
      <article></article>
      <article></article>
    </section>
```

- And my associated CSS code :

```
    @media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
      section:last-of-type article {
        display: block !important;
      }

      section:nth-of-type(2) {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
        gap: 5px;
      }

      section article {
        height: 25vh;
        flex: 0 0 33% !important;
      }
    }

    section:nth-of-type(2) {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      gap: 5px;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }

    body {
      gap: 15px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
```

The problem occurs when I change the gap value in the section:nth-of-type(2) rule from 5px to 10px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Initial Problems:***

- I was using the CSS property `flex: 0 0 33%;` to set the width of each article to one-third of the total container width. However, this approach did not account for the gap between the articles.
- Additionally, I had different gap values depending on the screen size, which led to inconsistencies in the spacing between the articles.

***Solutions Implemented:***

- For the articles, I switched to using the property `flex: 0 0 calc((100% / 3) - 15px);`. This formula calculates the width of each article while taking into account a 15px gap between them. This ensures that both the articles and the gaps fit correctly within the container.
- I also adjusted the width of the header nav by using `flex: 0 0 calc(33% - 15px);`. This guarantees that the navigation section takes up exactly one-third of the container width while leaving a 15px space for the gap.

```
  body section:nth-of-type(2) article {
    flex: 0 0 calc((100% / 3) - 15px);
  }
  header nav {
    flex: 0 0 calc(33% - 15px);
  }
```